# Using async/await with a for loop for nested Axios calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios, es6-promise

I am using Axios to perform a GET request against Facebook Graph to get the list of Facebook Pages the user manages. Once I have that, then I am using a `for loop` to perform another GET request against Facebook Graph to pull data on each Facebook Page that the user manages. I am doing this inside of an `async function` with a `Promise` at the end to join all the data together into a single `const fbProfile`.

**My issue is:** I cannot get the results from the Axios call in `const pages` to populate `pages` array.

My code is below:

```
  async function getfbProfile(token) {
    try {
      const user = await axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me', {
        params: {
          access_token: `${token}`,
          fields: 'picture,accounts',
        },
      });
      const pages = await user.data.accounts.data.forEach((err, pageInfo) => {
        axios.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${user.data.accounts.data[pageInfo].id}`, {
          params: {
            access_token: `${token}`,
            fields: 'picture,name',
          },
        });
      });
      const fbProfile = await Promise.all([user, pages]);
      debug(fbProfile);
    } catch (err) {
      debug(err.stack);
    }
  }
```

I know that the first call goes through and the for loop calls go through. I verified the `for call` loop works by modifying `const pages` to look like below and seeing both calls successfully go to Facebook Graph.

```
  const pages = await user.data.accounts.data.forEach((err, pageInfo) => {
    axios.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${user.data.accounts.data[pageInfo].id}`, {
      params: {
        access_token: `${token}`,
        fields: 'picture,name',
      },
    })
      .then((result) => {
        debug(result);
      });
  });
```

I would greatly appreciate any help. I've been wracking my brains on this for the last two days. Thank you for any help you can give.

**ANSWER**

Thanks to [Patrick Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts) for his help. Since I am using Airbnb's ESLint profile, I had to modify his example below to pass linting. Thanks again!

```
  async function getfbProfile(token) {
    try {
      const user = await axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me', {
        params: {
          access_token: token,
          fields: 'picture,accounts',
        },
      });
      const pages = Promise.all(user.data.accounts.data.map(({ id }) => axios.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${id}`, {
        params: {
          access_token: token,
          fields: 'picture,name',
        },
      })));
      const fbProfile = await Promise.all([user, pages]);
      debug(fbProfile);
    } catch (err) {
      debug(err.stack);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Array.forEach()` returns `undefined`; you'll want to use `Array.map()` instead.

Comment: not really related, but why do you do  access_token: ${token} instead of just  access_token: token

Comment: The function you're passing to `map` needs to `return` the `axios.get(...)`

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka I honestly can't remember, thanks for helping me make that better by not having unnecessary code in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Promise.all()` isn't necessary for `user` because it isn't a promise, since you've unwrapped `axios.get()` using `await` already. `user.data.accounts.data.map(...)` is an *array* of promises (after you make [the fix I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693593/using-async-await-with-a-for-loop-for-nested-axios-calls#comment92314113_52693593)), so you shouldn't `await` it directly either.

Here's a simplified approach:

```
async function getfbProfile(token) {
  try {
    const user = axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me', {
      params: {
        access_token: token,
        fields: 'picture,accounts',
      },
    });
    const pages = Promise.all(user.data.accounts.data.map(({ id }) => {
      return axios.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${id}`, {
        params: {
          access_token: token,
          fields: 'picture,name',
        },
      });
    }));
    const fbProfile = await Promise.all([user, pages]);
    debug(fbProfile);
  } catch (err) {
    debug(err.stack);
  }
}
```

This way, `user` and `pages` requests can occur concurrently rather than sequentially. `await` halts control flow until the promise is resolved, so if you have requests that don't need to be sequential, it's better to create all of them with `axios.get()` before `await`ing all of them at once, if you can.

Comment: Thank you for the example Patrick. Since I am using Airbnb ESLint rules I had to modify it just a little, however, it works. Thank you VERY much!